# Наибольший общий делитель

Tags: линейная-алгебра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как ответ должен быть 7, так как не делятся на 5 первые числа в последовательности, но как именно посчитать? Знаю про алгоритм Евклида, но не понимаю как его здесь применить... Может подскажите ход решения?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из написанного вами выше следует, что осталось проверить все остальные члены на делимость на семь. Воспользуемся модулярной арифметикой и отдельно посчитаем каждый член выражения:

2^(3n) = 8^n = 1^n = 1 (mod 7)

3^(6n+2) = 9 * 9 ^(3n) = 2 * 2^(3n) = 2 * 8 ^ n = 2 (mod 7)

5^(6n+2) = 25 * 25^(3n) = 4 * 4^(3n) = 4 * 8^(2n)= 4 (mod 7)

1 + 2 + 4 = 7 = 0 (mod 7)

Вроде выглядит хорошо, но я абсолютно не уверен в правильности написанного мною.

Идею доказательства частично взял из [Признака Паскаля](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F). Про модулярную арифметику можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E), но честно говоря, лично я ее изучал путем проб и ошибок, поэтому и не уверен в написанном мною.